# how to I see the x and y values of a png image I've imported to vs code?

Tags: javascript

I'm following a tutorial that has 1 image for all the different sprites being used.

```
const sprite = new Image();
sprite.src = "img/sprite.png";
```

Then when the images need to be drawn on the canvas, I'm supposed to take segments from that image to render the pic I want to see.  Taking x and y values from the png and rendering what it needed.

```
const startBtn = {
    x : 120,
    y : 263,
    w : 83,
    h : 29
}
```

How can I get these x and y values?  Is there an extension that accomplishes something like that?

Comment: What do you mean by "*I've imported to vs code*"?

Comment: "imported" might not be the best word.  Just a png file I have in my project.  How can I get the x and y values from that png image and crop certain parts of the image accurately?